# EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, send

I am trying to send emails using phpmailer and getting the error as mentioned in the title. I am using XAMPP for apache server.
I have searched almost every link on google and everywhere but nothing is working for me.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require 'autoload.php';
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
//require 'class.smtp.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
//$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'language');
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";                            
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPAuth=False;  
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "password";
//$mail->setFrom("email@gmail.com");
$mail->From = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com','Rishabh Goel');
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = 'First Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Mail body in HTML';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the plain text version of the email content';
/*try{
$mail->Send();
echo "Thanks. Bug report successfully sent.
We will get in touch if we have any more questions!";
} catch(Exception $e){
//Something went bad
echo "Mailer Error: - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}*/
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: post complete error

Comment: Use the latest version of PHPMailer and base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). You have a very weird mix of things in here - it doesn't look like you've decided whether to use composer or not. You're also missing a vital option: `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'`; that will prevent your connection from working at all, but that problem goes away if you use the Gmail example.